calldata in the substrate contract ui
how can I get the calldata of the function in the wasm contract in the substrate contract UI ?
I was trying to mimic the behaviour of the upgradeToAndCall() of the solidity,but in that they are expecting the calldata and executing the function of the implementation using the calldata.
Can anyone help me in this ?
